# How to programmatically create a platform account on stripe

Tags: java, stripe-payments

I run System tests for my microservices that are using Stripe. In those tests I create Customers, Payment Methods and Charges on my platform account (listed on the top left in the Dashboard). The disavantage is that I have to first manually create a platform and then hard-code the platform's secret key in my code.

I would like to dynamically create account platforms (and get the keys) during the running time of the tests. Is there an API call or trick to do so directly from my code ?

PS : I tried to use Connect but each connected account created requires administrative informations difficult to mock, such as (Social Security Number) SSN, in order to perform charges on it. Thus making Connect an irrelevant service/solution in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a platform programmatically, no. You should just use the test keys of your platform.

You can definitely create connected accounts with your platform in test mode. Yes, you'll need to provide some information to verify the account to enable payments and transfers. Stripe provides [test verification data](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing#verification) you can use, so you'll just need to embed these values in your flow for creating test connected accounts.